# Userdata partially working but not installing boto3 on EC2 launch, have to explicitly install it

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, shell, boto3, ec2-userdata

The userdata script for my EC2:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erjan/MyVoteAWS/main/vote-processor/processor.py > /home/ec2-user/processor.py
cd /home/ec2-user/
sudo chmod +x processor.py
sudo yum -y install python3-pip
sudo yum -y install python3 python3-setuptools
pip3 install boto3 --user                   #this is not executed
./processor.py
```

The file processor.py is pulled from my GitHub repo, I do see it, but it's not launched because it needs boto3 - gives error:

```
"Import error: no boto3 module found"
```

I have to wait till it shows '2/2 checks passed' in the AWS GUI, then connect, then do explicitly type `pip3 install boto3 --user`, then I see progress bar downloading boto3, then my script processor.py works.

But it does not work out of box from userdata. What is the reason?

Comment: You should not use `sudo` in a User Data script because the script is executed as the `root` user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run your script using `python3`

```
python3 processor.py
```

Otherwise it runs probably under `python2`, which does not have `boto3` installed.

Comment: ok i will try, but when i did pip3 show boto3 (pip for version python3) - it still showed that no boto module was installed..

Comment: @ERJAN user-data runs under `root` user, not `ec2-user`. So if you just run `pip3 install boto3 --user` it will install in `root`, not `ec2-user`.

Comment: ok what i did was replace it with "sudo pip3 install boto3", it worked. however the script is not running - "./processor.py" is not launched when i login.. how to fix it?

Comment: @ERJAN Script not working is a new issue for new question. My answer and comments correctly address your original issue that you reported.